# is_plugin_active() returning false on active plugin

Tags: plugins, include

So I have the following in an include in my theme file:

```
include_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' );
if ( is_plugin_active( WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/woocommerce/woocommerce.php' ) ) {
  $shop_id = woocommerce_get_page_id( 'shop' );
  $shop_page = get_page( $shop_id );
}
```

but `is_plugin_active( WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/woocommerce/woocommerce.php')` is returning false, despite the fact that the plugin is active.

I'm wondering if `is_plugin_active()` might be tripped up by the theme customizer, because the fact that I'm doing this while hooked to `customize_preview_init` is the only gotcha that I can imagine would be causing issue.  Any insights?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`is_plugin_active()` expects just the base name of the plugin as parameter:

So use:

```
is_plugin_active( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php' );
```

The function will use the option `'active_plugins'` which is a list of plugins paths relative to the plugin directory already.

On a multi-site installation it will search in `get_site_option( 'active_sitewide_plugins')` too.

As an implementation note: Avoid these checks. Some users rename plugin names or directories. Test for the functions you will actually use instead, eg:

```
if ( function_exists( 'woocommerce_get_page_id' ) )
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: really appreciate that - must have been looking at an outdated commentary on the issue where the full path was included :/

Comment: I was finding the code I used to get active plugins and then check for woocommerce.php was failing if the plugin was network activated on a multisite as opposed to locally activated. Swapping to check if a base WooCommerce function exists like you described works in all scenarios. Thanks

Comment: Thank you, very reliable solution

Answer (score 3):

in case you dont know which plugins are active you can do the following.

```
// get array of active plugins
$active_plugins = (array) get_option( 'active_plugins', array() );
// see active plugins 'plugin-dir-name/plugin-base-file.php'
echo '<pre>';
print_r( $active_plugins );
echo '</pre>';
if ( ! empty( $active_plugins ) && in_array( 'plugin-dir-name/plugin-base-file.php', $active_plugins ) ) {
    // do something if plugin is active
}
```

for reference take a look into is_plugin_active function inside 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php'

```
function is_plugin_active( $plugin ) {
    return in_array( $plugin, (array) get_option( 'active_plugins', array() ) ) || is_plugin_active_for_network( $plugin );
}
```

Comment: I implemented this, but then ran into the issue noted in @fuxia's answer - that `get_option( 'active_plugins')` does not work on multisite.